# undefined variable in a laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i am new in laravel, i have a dropdown list and i want to populate it with years from 'UserController'
i dont want to write a long list of year, i just want years to be added on every year change.

**in my controller**

```
public function setYear(){
        $op="";
        for($i=2010;$i<date('Y')+1;$i++)
            {
                $op.="<option value=".$i.">".$i."</option></br>";
            }
         return View::make('admin.setYear')->with('options',$op);
    }
```

**in my view**

```
<select  name="gender">
  <option>Select</option>
    {{$op}}
</select>
```

i get this  `Undefined variable: op (View`

how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable name is `options`, not `$op`.

The name you pass in the `with()` the first parameter is what you use to access it in the view.

Switch `{{$op}}` to `{{$options}}`

Comment: If that has provided a solution to you please accept it as an answer by clicking the checkmark.